# file_get_contents not working from my server

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I am crawling a website using following code

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$header = file_get_contents('http://www.cinnetwork.org',false,$context);
print_r($header);
```

This code works correctly in phpfiddle. But when i use it from my server it says

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.cinnetwork.org): failed to open
>   stream: Connection timed out

I also tried using curl. It also shows the similar error.

Comment: is config `allow_url_fopen` turned on?

Comment: allow_url_fopen is turned on

Comment: the code works for other websites though.

Comment: it sounds like they're blocking you. Try using a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url= 'https://example.com';

$arrContextOptions=array(
  "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

Comment: works in phpfiddle but same error is shown while doing from my server failed to open stream: Connection timed out. But the same code works for other websites though

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion, you can use CURL instead ..

Comment: try with different url .. to make sure whether this website blocking something .. try to get data like yahoo and google with curl or then with file get contents ..

Comment: <?php


$ch = curl_init("http://www.cinnetwork.org");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
?>

Comment: i tried above code in my local server and its working fine .. there must be some module disabled or uninstalled in yor live server ..

Comment: the code works for other websites but does not work for this particular website. But when i try the same code for same website in http://phpfiddle.org/  it works

Comment: check curl error by using code something like below .. 
// Check if any error occurred
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

Comment: How can i know which module stopped working. My server is  from hostgator

Comment: if it works for other domains but not that address you want then perhaps they're blocking requests by user agent, IP or something.

Comment: Call your ISP and ask them. That's the easiest way. This is likely a firewall issue.

Comment: It might be server side issue, might be your server cannot communicate with other server remotely. You have to communicate with server administrator.

Comment: <?php 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
echo file_get_contents("http://yourwebsite.com");
?>

Comment: file_get_contents(http://www.website.com): failed to open stream: Connection timed out